# "a feeler gauge set no. 4" vs. "a no. 4 feeler gauge set"

Tags: word-order

My translation:

> Pipe straightness inspection
>
> Sufficient manufacturing compliance is generally enough to ensure pipe straightness. In questionable cases or when it is required by the regulatory documentation, the actual straightness of the pipe is checked using a 1 m straightedge tool and **a feeler gauge set no. 4**.

Would it be okay to say "a no. 4 feeler gauge set"? Which is better?

There are standards for feeler gauge sets in Russia (the particular document is called TU 3936-214-54769955-2008). There are four kinds of standard sets. Thus, when you buy a set of a particular number, you know what feeler gauges it includes.

Comment: The acceptable gap in fractions of a millimeter would be an informative "translator's gloss" to #4.  After a quick check, it seems the max thickness of a #4 feeler gauge is 1mm and the min is 0.1mm

Comment: @TRomano - yes, the range is from 0.1 to 1.0 mm. Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is probably not a lot of difference, but I would use:

> a no. 4 feeler gauge set

since *no. 4* modifies (defines) the kind of feeler gauge set. Same as why you would say:

> a heavy-duty feeler gauge set

and not

> a feeler gauge set heavy-duty

Answer (score 4):

I don't know feeler gauges specifically, but in AmE, generally with tools and hardware we put the number identifier first, like "#9 Nail" and "#2 Philips Screwdriver." So I would say "#4 feeler gauge set."

But if you're doing this translation for a specific audience (like, say, UK or US mechanics), you might want to make sure that these standard sets are available and are called by the same name for that audience as they are for the document's original audience.

Comment: I'm not sure if there are governmental standards for feeler gauge sets in the US, and that these standards include only four sets, like in Russia.